# Player.EventListener is deprecated how to use instead of Player.Listener in Java

Tags: java, android, deprecated, event-listener, exoplayer

In Exoplayer version `2.14.1` `Playerd.EventListener()` is deprecated. when I read docs its says use instead of `Player.Listener`, but I have no idea how to use that method like below code.

```
simpleExoPlayer.addListener(new Player.EventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPlaybackStateChanged(int state) {
                if (state == simpleExoPlayer.STATE_READY) {

                    aspectRatioFrameLayout.setAspectRatio(16f / 9f);
                } else {
                    playerView.hideController();
                }
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

As per there [Documentation](https://exoplayer.dev/listening-to-player-events.html) you would want something like:

```
simpleExoPlayer.addListener(new Player.Listener() {
        @Override
        public void onPlaybackStateChanged(@State int state) {
            if (state == Player.STATE_READY) {

                aspectRatioFrameLayout.setAspectRatio(16f / 9f);
            } else {
                playerView.hideController();
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: @GaneshMB great! please mark my answer if you are happy :)

Answer (score 5):

In **Kotlin** use this code, for more details refer to this  [Documentation](https://exoplayer.dev/listening-to-player-events.html)

```
 player!!.addListener(object : Player.Listener { // player listener

            override fun onPlayerStateChanged(playWhenReady: Boolean, playbackState: Int) {
                when (playbackState) { // check player play back state
                    Player.STATE_READY -> {
                      aspectRatioFrameLayout.setAspectRatio(16f / 9f)
                    }
                    Player.STATE_ENDED -> { 
                         //your logic 
                    }
                    Player.STATE_BUFFERING ->{ 
                         //your logic 
                    }
                    Player.STATE_IDLE -> { 
                         //your logic 
                    }
                    else -> {
                       playerView.hideController()
                    }
                }
            }
        })
```

Comment: sorry Tippu currently I'm working with java but I appreciate you its also needs for later

Comment: Okay got it, hope it will use for other's.

Comment: onPlayerStateChanged deprecated. Use onPlaybackStateChanged(int) and onPlayWhenReadyChanged(boolean, int) instead
https://exoplayer.dev/doc/reference/com/google/android/exoplayer2/Player.Listener.html#onPlayerStateChanged(boolean,@com.google.android.exoplayer2.Player.Stateint)

Answer (score 1):

```
        exoPlayer.addListener(new Player.Listener() {
            public void onPlaybackStateChanged(int playbackState) {
                if(playbackState == Player.STATE_ENDED){
                    ..............
                }
            }
        });
```

This works for me on March 2022

Answer (score 0):

Now in player version 2 it has changed

```java
player?.addListener(object :Player.EventListener{
    
    override fun onPlayerStateChanged(playWhenReady: Boolean, playbackState: Int) {
        super.onPlayerStateChanged(playWhenReady, playbackState)
        if (playbackState == Player.STATE_READY) {
                        
        } else {
                       
        }
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use new version: `com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer:2.18.6`

This function deprecated:

```kotlin
@Deprecated
    default void onPlayerStateChanged(boolean playWhenReady, @State int playbackState) {}
```

New function is:

```kotlin
 default void onPlaybackStateChanged(@State int playbackState) {}
```

New usage:

```kotlin
exoPlayer?.addListener(object : Player.Listener {
            override fun onPlaybackStateChanged(@Player.State state: Int) {
                when (state) {
                    Player.STATE_READY -> {
                        // The player is able to immediately play from its current position. The player will be playing if getPlayWhenReady() is true, and paused otherwise.
                    }
                    Player.STATE_BUFFERING -> {
                       // The player is not able to immediately play the media, but is doing work toward being able to do so. This state typically occurs when the player needs to buffer more data before playback can start.
                    }
                    Player.STATE_IDLE -> {
                       // The player is idle, meaning it holds only limited resources.The player must be prepared before it will play the media.
                    }
                    Player.STATE_ENDED -> { 
                       // The player has finished playing the media.
                    }
                    else -> {
                      // Other things
                    }
                }
            }
        })
```